# How to check whether HDD is sleeping?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sleep, power

There is a setting in Windows power settings to put HDD to sleep when innactive. I would like to know when exactly this setting is getting applied to have better understanding/control of power consumption and lifetime of HDD.

I have set the settings to 1 minute of innactivity and left my PC innactive for some time (and tried to ensure that no software is being run from that HDD, nor should any software access anything on that HDD) and when I came back, I tried to browse that HDD and it worked right away - there was no delay during which the HDD would power up (if it was asleep).

I had task manager opened and there were no writes/reads of that HDD. I have checked windows events about some HDD info, but there was nothing there. In device manager, there is a "Power data" section in Properties->Details of HDD, but it doesn't seem to change - it always displays "Current power state: D0".

So, how to monitor the "sleep" state of HDD?

Answer (score 0):

First, there are solid-state buffers on some HDD's, so immediate availability is not proof that the drive was sleeping. The easiest way to tell is by listening -- quite evident on external disk drives, but harder to hear startup on an internal HD (might try a stethoscope ;-).

You might also use a disk state monitor, such as [Activity Indicator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/activityindicat/), along with the aforementioned aural activity detection, to see if there is any actual read/write activity logged.

*N.B.* Windows is *continually* accessing the HDD, particularly the partition with the system files, for many tasks, such as:

- Malware checking
- File indexing
- File system optimization
- File system cleanup
- Checking for Windows updates

For that reason, the HDD may rarely sleep, even if sleep is correctly enabled. On the other hand, sleep might not actually extend the service life of the HDD. Each time a drive starts, the disk needs to come up to speed before [the heads float above the surface on a cushion of air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_read-and-write_head) (or helium in some newer drives). Though the platters might have a diamond-like coating, the highest friction is on startup, so there is some thought that continuous operation is not as detrimental as frequent starts and stops.

BTW, In one test, [~80% of the drives surveyed were in service after four years use](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/170748-how-long-do-hard-drives-actually-live-for).

Comment: The Activity Indicator is nice one - thanks for the tip. Also it validated that I really have 0 activities on that HDD (I have disabled defender and it's not a system HDD - it's just storage HDD, so it may be true). It's a 10TB WD RED HDD in a desktop PC, that I am using as a NAS + some other services, but there are times (days, weeks) that I am not using the NAS functionality at all - just the other services, that are not using the HDD. And was wondering, whether it would be meaningful to not keep that HDD fully powered up during this time.

Comment: Of course if the startup/powerdown cycle would occur often (like once per hour), it may cause more harm than good. But if the cycle is days/weeks, it may be a little profitable, doesn't it?